# Ionic Deploy not updating Snapshot

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to get the latest snapshot from Ionic cloud and install it onto an Android device. I have copied the code directly from the Ionic Deploy docs and the code works fine without errors however does not seem to actually update my old files with the new ones I uploaded onto Ionic Cloud

Using: **ionic upload --note "version x"**

I then go to the Cloud and click **Deploy**. When viewing the log feed in the console log (from Android device) I can see that the Snapshot was *found*, *downloaded* and *extracted*.

However, even a simple text change in one file is not visible in the app on my Android device. Is there another function I need to call after **$ionicDeploy.extract(); or $ionicDeploy.load();**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ionic.cloud', 'starter.services','ngCordova','ngStorage','chart.js','angular-svg-round-progress'])

    .config(function($ionicCloudProvider) {

      $ionicCloudProvider.init({
        "core": {
          "app_id": "xxxxxxxx"
        }
      });
    })

    .run(function($http,$ionicPlatform,$rootScope,$cordovaBluetoothSerial,$cordovaStatusbar,$window,$cordovaSQLite,$ionicDeploy) {

      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
           $rootScope.alreadyUpdated = 'false';

           if($rootScope.alreadyUpdated == 'false') 
           {
              $ionicDeploy.check().then(function(snapshotAvailable) {
                      // When snapshotAvailable is true, you can apply the snapshot
                     $ionicDeploy.download().then(function() {
                          return $ionicDeploy.extract();

                          $ionicDeploy.load();
                          $rootScope.alreadyUpdated = 'true';
                        });
                 });
              console.log("MOST recent");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The line before `$ionicDeploy.load()` is `return $ionicDeploy.extract();`, this means you will never get to the `$ionicDeploy.load()` part (the `return` keyword makes it unreachable code - any decent IDE will even highlight this for you).

you should replace this part with:

```
$ionicDeploy.extract().then(function() {
    console.log("Extracted");
    $ionicDeploy.load();
    $rootScope.alreadyUpdated = 'true';  //this also is not needed FYI, but I left it to keep your code intact. see note
});
```

**Note** - after `$ionicDeploy.load()`, there is no need to call `$rootScope.alreadyUpdated`. This is because the `load()` function will reload the app, so the scopes will be reinitialized, just as if you opened the app for the first time.

good luck

Comment: How can I get $ionicDeploy.load() to also call the run block again or onDevice ready?